# WSJ WebScraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to get this value from the WSJ web page:

[image]

I am using this code however it is not working correctly I get a none result and I don't know why:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/bonds'


HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Value = soup.find("td", attrs={"class": "WSJTables--table__cell--2u6629rx WSJTheme--table__cell--3njwWeaF"})
print(Value)
```

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup doesnt work in this case as the output is not properly formatted as html. You can replace the last 4 lines with

```
page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
pattern = re.compile('"data":\{"instruments":\[(.+?)\]')
data = pattern.findall(page.text)
cleaned = data[0].replace('null','"null"')
output = list(eval(cleaned))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'djId': '516585', 'mantissa': 5, 'name': 'Federal-Funds Rate Target', 'yieldRateLast': '0.00 - 0.25', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '0.00 - 0.25', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '1.50 - 1.75', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '0.00 - 0.25', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-1.50', 'changePercentThreeYear': '-1.00', 'timestamp': '2020-03-16T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': {'yieldRateLast': {'max': 0.250000000000001, 'min': 1e-15}, 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': {'max': 0.250000000000001, 'min': 1e-15}, 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': {'max': 1.75, 'min': 1.5}, 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': {'max': 0.250000000000001, 'min': 1e-15}}, 'formattedName': 'Federal-Funds Rate Target'}, {'djId': '501335', 'mantissa': 2, 'name': 'WSJ Prime Rate', 'yieldRateLast': '3.25', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '3.25', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '4.75', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '3.25', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-1.50', 'changePercentThreeYear': '-1.00', 'timestamp': '2020-03-16T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': 'null', 'formattedName': 'WSJ Prime Rate*'}, {'djId': '516617', 'mantissa': 2, 'name': 'Money Market, Annual Yield', 'yieldRateLast': '0.20', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '0.21', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '0.58', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '0.19', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-0.37', 'changePercentThreeYear': '-0.14', 'timestamp': '2020-12-03T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': 'null', 'formattedName': 'Money Market, Annual Yield'}, {'djId': '516981', 'mantissa': 2, 'name': 'Five-Year CD, Annual Yield', 'yieldRateLast': '0.58', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '0.58', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '1.41', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '0.58', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-0.83', 'changePercentThreeYear': '-0.91', 'timestamp': '2020-12-03T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': 'null', 'formattedName': 'Five-Year CD, Annual Yield'}, {'djId': '517011', 'mantissa': 2, 'name': '30-Year Mortgage, Fixed', 'yieldRateLast': '2.94', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '2.95', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '4.22', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '2.90', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-0.96', 'changePercentThreeYear': '-0.94', 'timestamp': '2020-12-03T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': 'null', 'formattedName': '30-Year Mortgage, Fixed'}, {'djId': '517010', 'mantissa': 2, 'name': '15-Year Mortgage, Fixed', 'yieldRateLast': '2.37', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '2.43', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '3.57', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '2.37', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-0.97', 'changePercentThreeYear': '-0.93', 'timestamp': '2020-12-03T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': 'null', 'formattedName': '15-Year Mortgage, Fixed'}, {'djId': '517009', 'mantissa': 2, 'name': 'Jumbo Mortgage, Fixed', 'yieldRateLast': '2.97', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '2.99', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '4.36', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '2.90', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-1.26', 'changePercentThreeYear': '-1.33', 'timestamp': '2020-12-03T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': 'null', 'formattedName': 'Jumbo Mortgage, Fixed'}, {'djId': '516967', 'mantissa': 2, 'name': 'Five-Year Adj Mortgage (ARM)', 'yieldRateLast': '3.21', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '3.21', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '4.61', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '2.85', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-1.20', 'changePercentThreeYear': '-0.49', 'timestamp': '2020-12-03T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': 'null', 'formattedName': 'Five-Year Adj Mortgage (ARM)'}, {'djId': '516973', 'mantissa': 2, 'name': 'New-Car Loan, 48-Month', 'yieldRateLast': '4.04', 'yieldRateOneWeekAgo': '4.04', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': '4.50', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow': '4.04', 'changePercentFiftyTwoWeek': '-0.37', 'changePercentThreeYear': '0.84', 'timestamp': '2020-12-03T00:00:00-05:00', 'yieldRateRanges': 'null', 'formattedName': 'New-Car Loan, 48-Month'}]
```

As you can see, each table row has an id which is always the same everyday eg WSJ Prime Rate is 501335. You can manipulate the list to a dictionary of ids and target exactly what you need.

In the simplest form you can get the WSJ Prime Rate from the list using:

```
wsj = output[1]['yieldRateLast']
```

This will give you the yield rate of `3.25` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**It is a JavaScript rendered page**

When you look at the raw HTML output from BeautifulSoup, it cannot find anything because that element does not yet exist on the page. There is some JavaScript which first needs to execute for that element to be there. You need to use a scraping solution that allows JavaScript execution such as Selenium Webdriver.